# Using KDE style in pure Qt app under Windows

Tags: windows, qt, colors, kde-plasma

How can i use KDE style in pure Qt app's under Windows?

Thanks

Comment: No )) I want to use KDE-Ubuntu Themes in my QT application under windows

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can specify the style:

```
YourApp.exe -style plastique
```

I believe plastique is the default style for Qt/X11 applications running under KDE.

Within code, you can also use `QApplication::setStyle`.

Comment: Yes. But how can i convert QT/KDE4-specific themes to .qss files ? )

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. My Qt installation has the plastique style built-in (on Windows). I didn't have to convert anything. Maybe I'm not understanding the question....